# How to fix '_react["default"].memo is not a function. (In '_react["default"].memo(connectFunction)' error in React native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am trying to connect Redux mapStateToProps() and mapActionCreators() to Login Screen through Container and I am using React navigation.

After build my app the following error message appears:

> _react["default"].memo is not a function. (In '_react["defaults"].memo(connectFunction)', '_react["defaults"].memo' is undefined.

I searched for a while but what I have gotten is that React.memo() helps us control when our components rerender but I don't use any code related to React.memo().

Login Screen: (screens/LoginScreen/index.js)

```
import React from 'react';
import {Dimensions, View} from 'react-native';

//Get width of mobile screen
var width = Dimensions.get("window").width;
var height = Dimensions.get("window").height;

export default class LoginScreen extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {

        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>Log In page</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

LoginScreen.defaultProps = {
}

const styles = {
    container: {
        flex: 1
    }
}
```

Login screen container: (containers/LoginContainer/index.js)

```
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import LoginScreen from "../../screens/LoginScreen";

const mapStateToProps = (state) =>({

});


const mapActionCreators = {

};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionCreators)(LoginScreen);
```

Top level navigation: (navigations/TopLevelSwitchNav.js)

```
import {createSwitchNavigation, createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
import LoginScreen from '../containers/LoginContainer';
import MainTabNav from './MainTabNav';


const TopLevelSwitchNav = createSwitchNavigation({
    Login:  {
        screen: LoginScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
            header: null
        }
    },
    MainTab: {
        screen: MainTabNav,
        navigationOptions: {
            header: null
        }
    }
},
{
    initialRouteName: Login,
    navigationOptions: { header: null }
});

export default createAppContainer(TopLevelSwitchNav);
```

Dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "expo": "^32.0.0",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-navigation": "^3.8.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.0.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-persist": "^5.10.0",
    "redux-persist-transform-filter": "^0.0.18",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
},
```

Answer (score 14):

I solved it, it seems that React-Redux package depend on React 16.8.0 and uses React.memo() somehow so I downgraded React-Redux to v6.0.0

Comment: 1. Go to your package.json file and change the "react-redux" version to "6.0.0"

2. run npm install

Answer (score 13):

Same as the solutions above but with instructions. Be sure to clear the Expo cache!

Downgrade your react-redux to version 6.0.1

```
npm install react-redux@6.0.1
```

Clear the cache in Expo

```
expo r -c
```

Answer (score 2):

Downgrade your react-redux to v6.0.0 and start your expo project by
**expo r -c** which resets the cache

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment yet, so adding this as an addition to Ahmed Saeed's response [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55693526/4588517). 
As of today, April 17, Hooks are not supported on Expo yet, read more [here](https://forums.expo.io/t/react-default-memo-is-not-a-function/21623). From v.7.0.1 react-redux

> connect now uses React.memo() internally, which returns a special
>   object rather than a function.

And it's [rewritten](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/releases/tag/v7.0.1) with Hooks. Downgrading react-redux to v.6.0.0 helps.